# Reactjs - SPA Routing using a Navbar

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-navigation

**Problem**
I want to start off by saying that I am still new to reactjs and nodejs as a whole. I am working on a dynamic NavBar for a Single Page Application (SPA), but I am struggling with the routing. It took me some time, but I got the routing to work in general. For some reason, the "topics" and "about" pages will load properly (without reloading the whole page); however, the two reports (General Reports and International Reports) Nav options will reload the page with each click, defeating the purpose of a SPA. I looked through tutorial after tutorial just to get this far... I am hoping someone here can assist in pointing out what I am doing wrong.

**The Code**
This is the Navbar code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Navbar, Nav, NavItem, NavLink, MenuItem, NavDropdown } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router';
import { getUserGroup } from './Auth.jsx'; /*this is a mock file, the code only assigns a role that I can control by changing a "username"*/

var isDev = getUserGroup() === "dev" ? true : false;
var isAdmin = getUserGroup() === "admin" ? true : false;
var isDataAnalyst = getUserGroup() === "analyst" ? true : false;

/* setup this way intentionally to dynamically render the Navigation bar */
var renderUserVerify = !isDataAnalyst ? <MenuItem eventKey={1.1} href="/UserVerfication">USER VERIFICATION</MenuItem> : null;
var renderPkgLookup = !isDataAnalyst ? <MenuItem eventKey={1.2} href="/PkgInqueryn">PACKAGE INQUERY</MenuItem> : null;
var renderQuerySearch = !isDataAnalyst ? <NavDropdown eventKey={1} title="QUERY SEARCHES" id="query-nav-dropdown">
                                           {renderUserVerify}
                                           {renderPkgLookup}
                                         </NavDropdown> : null;

var renderUpdateUser = isDev || isAdmin ? <NavItem eventKey={2} href="/UpdateUser">UPDATE USER</NavItem> : null;

var renderFPReports = isDev || isAdmin || isDataAnalyst ? <MenuItem eventKey={3.1} href="/reports/GenReports">GENERAL REPORTS</MenuItem> : null;
var renderIntlReports = isDev || isAdmin || isDataAnalyst ? <MenuItem eventKey={3.2} href="/reports/IntlReports">INTERNATIONAL REPORTS</MenuItem> : null;
var renderReports = isDev || isAdmin || isDataAnalyst ? <NavDropdown eventKey={3} title="REPORTS" id="reports-nav-dropdown">
                                                          {renderGenReports}
                                                          {renderIntlReports}
                                                        </NavDropdown> : null;
var renderUserPref = !isDataAnalyst ? <NavItem eventKey={4} href="/UserPref">USER PREFERENCE</NavItem> : null;

export default class Navigation extends React.Component {
  handleSelect(eventKey) {
    /*event.preventDefault();*/
    this.state.href
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar inverse fluid collapseOnSelect>
          <Navbar.Header>
            <Navbar.Brand>
              <a href="/"> CPMS </a>
            </Navbar.Brand>
            <Navbar.Toggle />
          </Navbar.Header>
          <Navbar.Collapse>
            <Nav onSelect={c => this.handleSelect(c)}>
              {renderQuerySearch}
              {renderUpdateUser
              {renderReports}
              {renderUserPref}
              <NavItem eventKey={5} href="/Help">HELP</NavItem>
              <NavItem eventKey={6} href="/logout">LOGOUT</NavItem>
            </Nav>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This is the routing code:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, HashRouter, NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import GenReports from '../pages/GenReports';
import IntlReports from '../pages/IntlReports';

const BodyContent = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/about" component={About} /> /* dummy page for testing routing */
      <Route path="/topics" component={Topics} /> /* dummy page for testing routing */
      <Route path="/Reports/GenReports" component={GenReports} />
      <Route path="/Reports/IntlReports" component={IntlReports} />
    </div>
  </Router>
);

const Home = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>This is the home page</h2>
  </div>
);

const About = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>About</h2>
  </div>
);

const Topics = ({ match }) => (
  <div>
    <h2>Topics</h2>
      <NavLink to={`${match.url}/rendering`}>Rendering with React</NavLink><br />
      <NavLink to={`${match.url}/components`}>Components</NavLink><br />
      <NavLink to={`${match.url}/props-v-state`}>Props v. State</NavLink><br />

    <Route path={`${match.url}/:topicId`} component={Topic} />
    <Route
      exact
      path={match.url}
      render={() => <h3>Please select a topic.</h3>}
    />
  </div>
);

const Topic = ({ match }) => (
  <div>
    <h3>{match.params.topicId}</h3>
  </div>
);

export default BodyContent;
```

This is the code for the App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Navigation from './components/NavComponent';
import BodyContent from './components/RoutingComponent';    
import 'react-bootstrap';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <Navigation />
        <BodyContent />
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This is the GenReports page (the other reports page is setup the same way)

```
import React from 'react';

export default class IntlReports extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
     <h1>You have reached the General Reports Page</h1>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Click on this one is switch to GenReports page ? `<MenuItem eventKey={3.1} href="/reports/GenReports">GENERAL REPORTS</MenuItem>`

Comment: Yes, this options should switch to GenReports. If you are testing it yourself, you might have to remove the dynamic rendering part of the component or modify it so that the necessary setting is "true" to load the component. Overall, the routing works, but any of the navbar options, like GenReports, will reload the page completely instead of just re-rendering the view with the new content.

Comment: So, change it like this, `<NavLink to="/reports/GenReports" >GENERAL REPORTS</NavLink>` Seem href is problem. Make sure you have `import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';`

Comment: Just to be sure I understand: switch out the `MenuItem` tag for the `NavLink` tag?

Comment: Ah! I got it. Okay, Thank you very much @TruongDang that helped me achieve my goal.